# Get unique row by certain values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have the following data:

[image]

I want to get by using an excel formula all rows which are unique for the first time by its `date` and its `value`. So by an example: In the `2` row of the picture this row is unique, whereas the `3` row is not unique because the first row came up. In contrast the `7th` row is unique and the `8th` row also, but not the `9th`  because its the same as the `8th` row.

I expect the following results:

[image]

I tried to implement it like that:

`=IF(MATCH(A2:B2;$A$2:B2;0);1;0)`

However as you can see I only get `#VALUE`. Any suggestions on how to implement that?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the number of times this combination happens in any rows above or at this line.  If the number comes out as 1 this is the first time you've seen it and flag it as 1.

Put the function in cell C2 and copy down.

Gordon

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2)=1,1,0)
```